# Rails doesn't seem to have been added to Ubuntu path

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I am a newbie with Ubuntu (12:04) and I'm trying to install rails on it. I did use rvm and I used the command `gem install rails`. Everything seemed to go well. But when i try to use the rails command (rails -v, rails console) anything, the output is that rails was not installed.

Essentially the same exact issue as here: http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2009/07/installing-rails-on-ubuntu-path-problem.html

however the fix was to use `# export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH` But I don't see this folder location on my system. Perhaps folder locations have changed with newer rails versions. I even tried to look in the rvm gem bin but didn't see any rails in there. Any help?

Comment: If you installed 'rvm' then your path will vary depending upon which ruby you selected. If 'rvm' is installed correctly, it should set up the path. Check your 'rvm' installation. If you set it up for individual use, your ruby/rails/gem path will be somewhere under `/home/my_login/.rvm`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I've just navigated to that `ruby/gem/rails` folder and it's completely empty. Should it be like that?

Comment: Did you set up rvm for a single user or for everyone? (It's an option during the install process) If individual, what do you see if you do `ls ~/.rvm/gems`?

Comment: ls there shows me:  `cache  ruby-1.9.3-p429  ruby-1.9.3-p429@global` I'm not sure if I did for everyone or single user. I used this command: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it must be determined if `rvm` appears to be properly installed:

```
rvm list
```

Should show available Rubies. In particular, `ruby-1.9.3-p429` should be listed there based upon what your directory shows. Then, select the Ruby that's installed:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

This should execute successfully. Type:

```
ruby --version
```

Should give you the version of ruby and it should be 1.9.3-p429. If it's not or it gives you an error, you'll need to start over and reinstall `rvm` per instructions the [RVM site](http://rvm.io).

If that is successful, then go to your Rails project folder and type in:

```
gem install rails
```

That should properly install rails for the selected Ruby under rvm. After that, check that it's installed by typing (from within the same folder):

```
rails --version
```

If this isn't working, `echo $PATH` and make sure your `~/.rvm/...` directories are there. Check that the `bin` directories have these commands. If they don't, then there's something wrong with your `rvm` installation.

Comment: rails -v still comes up empty and I've just re-installed rvm too and did the whole process `The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails` I think it's installed because it comes up in `gem list rails` However I have a project on git that I needed to work on. using `gem install rails` seemed to have worked there, but only for that specific folder

Comment: If that's the case, then you may have set up a .ruby-version or other project-specific rvm setting, which is fine. You could go to your home directory and try the `gem install rails`. If that doesn't work, then it sounds to me like there's something you may have missed in the rvm instructions. They do suggest some things to check in your shell startup scripts. But rvm is ideal for having different setups per Rails project. There really isn't a need to run Rails outside of a project folder.

Comment: i tried echo PATH, .rvm/bin seems to be in there. but rails doesn't seem to be in there. How can i add rails to this bin folder?

Comment: It should have more than that. It should also have something similar to `/home/my_login/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin` and `/home/my_login/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/bin`. If you are using project specific rvm settings, then you'd have an `@myproject` in there somewhere. If not, then it's not setup correctly.

Comment: There are instructions at the rvm website about ensuring your .bash_profile has something like this in it: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` If you don't have those other bin directories in your path, then that script line is probably missing.

Comment: hey, thanks for all your persistence up to this point. you were right, there was supposed to be more in the `echo $PATH` I think I was missing: `user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` But the critical mistake was forgetting to exit out of the terminal session and opening a new one. I think. but for inside all my git projects, I still need to do a `gem install rails` along w/ `bundle install` - i guess it's just normal. Though it wasn't this way in Windows.  Thanks so much man.

Comment: Yep that would do it. The path has to get updated from the bash profile. Great! Glad that's resolved. :)